# Laravel deep routing with multiple optional values

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I am looking for the best way to approach this.

I have a form that posts a simple search, however there are multiple optional values.  The controller then redirects the post to a URL that is easier to read.

e.g.

```
startdate=2018-01-01
enddate=2018-01-31
department=2,4
```

this would create a URL

```
/2018-01-01/2018-01-31/2,4/
```

But if they also search by employee it would then return the following

```
employee=9,5,1
/2018-01-01/2018-01-31/2,4/9,5,1/
```

They could also not search for department and just search for employees

```
/2018-01-01/2018-01-31/???/9,5,1/
```

So with that in mind the full URL route plan is showing below, how would you go about having nested optional attributes?  Also how would you then get those values in the route afterwards?

```
Route::get('/{locale}/WIPReport/show/{startdate}/{enddate}/{regions?}/{offices?}/{departments?}/{clients?}/{employees?}', 'WIPReportController@reportdata')
    ->where(['regions' => '[0-9,]+', 'offices' => '[0-9,]+', 'departments' => '[0-9,]+', 'clients' => '[0-9,]+', 'employees' => '[0-9,]+'])
```

Comment: Wouldn't these work better as a query string?

Comment: Multiple optional Route Parameters can be used, but unless you put `/null` or `/0`, etc. into your URL and handle accordingly, you'll run into problems. Consider using a query string, handle via `POST`, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis I thought as much.  I had thought about keeping the post data as post, but there is another feature where they can bookmark reports for re-creation so that wouldn't work.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple optional Route Parameters can be used, but unless you put `/null`, `/none`, `/0`, etc. you're bound to run into problems. Take this URL and Route for example:

```
Route::get("{primary?}/{secondary?}/{tertiary?}", ExampleController@handleColours);

public function handleColours($primary = null, $secondary = null, $tertiary = null){
  // Handle URL
}

"mysite.com/red/blue/green"
```

In the above, everything works fine, as all 3 are defined. Dropping `green` would also be fine, as `$tertiary` would default to `null`. Next, given this route:

```
"mysite.com/red/green"
```

If you intended `green` to be tertiary, and were expecting results based on that, you'd run into the issue of `$secondary` not being defined in the URL, so `$secondary` would be `green` and not `null`. If you change the URL to

```
"mysite.com/red/null/green"
// OR
"mysite.com/red/none/green"
// OR
"mysite.com/red/0/green"
```

Then things would behave as expected (given a bit of extra logic to translate the string `"null"` or `"none"` to `null`), but the URL can get a bit muddy. Other option would be using a query string to explicitly specific parameters:

```
"mysite.com?primary=red&tertiary=green"
```

So there's options to handle in multiple ways; go with whatever works best for you.

Comment: I accepted this answer, it doesn't answer the question fully but it does point out the failure in the design of the implementation and ways to resolve it using 0 or null